# Upgrading to new iPad, how can I get old settings and apps directly to new iPad?

Tags: ipad, upgrade

I bought iPad 2 but it is very poor during lectures, very poor camera and storing A4 papers very imprecise. I have over 100 Apps, done all email settings and other things -- probably over 10 hours' tuning. I don't want to do it again. How can I get my settings from my old iPad to my new iPad?

I don't have yet a Mac -computer but my friends have. My friend said that it would be easy if I had a Mac -computer so I am wondering whether only easy way is to get a Mac to get things synced fast?!

*P.s. I have also a license to Windows 7 Professional. If all I need is actually just iTunes, I could virtualize W7pro and install iTunes to get things configured. Does it work?*

Comment: ...I am also interested about this: suppose I would like to have over 20 iPads. Is it possible to get the same settings to them fast? One iPad would have a lot of paid apps, I am trying to find out how I can get it so that everyone is using the same apps and same iPads with the same settings -- and only email/etc personalized.

Comment: That comment deserves to be its own, separate question. There are mechanisms for provisioning a large number of iOS devices that are distinct from the steps taken to restore a single new device.

Comment: @DanJ roger, moved it [here](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/69625/getting-ipads-ready-with-paid-apps-and-customized-settings-for-a-large-amount-of).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have iOS 5 or 6 installed on your iPad, you can use the [iCloud Backup](http://www.macworld.com/article/1162955/icloud_backup.html) functionality to transfer all your settings and apps, without the need for another computer. When you set up your new iPad, it will ask whether you want to set it up as a new iPad, or restore from an iTunes or iCloud backup.

Restoring from an iCloud backup will restore nearly everything, with the exception of any saved Wi-Fi or other passwords, which you'll have to re-enter. Alternately, doing a backup and restore from iTunes on a Mac or PC will restore passwords *if you encrypt the backup*.

Apple's support site has more details in this article: [iOS: Transferring information from your current iPhone, iPad, or iPod touch to a new device](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT2109).

Comment: Is there some way to see the backup in iCloud.com? I mean how can I make sure things went well?