# Getting iPads ready with paid apps and customized settings for a large amount of personnel?

Tags: ipad, mobile-device-management

Suppose I would like to have over 20 iPads. Is it possible to get the same settings to them fast? One iPad would have a lot of paid apps, I am trying to find out how I can get it so that everyone is using the same apps and same iPads with the same settings -- and only email/etc personalized.

I believe there is no sense that I shared my own iPad's backup, [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/69623/upgrading-to-new-ipad-how-can-i-get-old-settings-and-apps-directly-to-new-ipad). I want to make sure all people have the best tools/apps/etc in their iPads before starting to work.

It would be a big plus if the manager could install/upgrade new apps in iPads without other people to worry so everyone running the same apps of the same version number.

Comment: ...why one answer removed about easier process with Mountain Lion -server? I would like to know whether it was true or totally false?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple has a whole [section of their support site](http://www.apple.com/support/ipad/enterprise/) for deploying iPads "to the Enterprise". What you'll likely find the most useful are the items about the Apple Configurator, which is a free app ([available here](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/apple-configurator/id434433123?mt=12)) for managing and configuring large numbers of iOS devices.

You may also be interested in [this Ars Technica article](http://arstechnica.com/apple/2012/09/locking-up-locking-down-hands-on-with-ios-6-enterprise-management/) about iOS 6's management features.

Answer (score 1):

Installing Moutain Lion server will give you greater control, via profile manager,

try http://help.apple.com/advancedserveradmin/mac/10.8/#apd88330954-6FA0-4568-A88E-7F6828E763A7

on the left pane scroll to Manage users, then Profile manager. It will describe the use of administrator controlled configuration files suitable for setting policies, applications and settings for macs and iOS devices.

Comment: If you can expand on your thoughts within this answer (post links to sources, screenshots of the utility, explain how this app works at a basic level), flag your answer and I will undelete it.